# Скрипт не запускается командой python3, а python3.8 не запускается. Куда копать?

Tags: python, venv

Так скрипт успешно запускается и работает
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вот python3 не видит библиотек. Как исправить? У меня 2 python интерпретатора что ли? Библиотеки ставлю с помощью pip3. Хочу разобраться в чем суть происходящего и быть может избаиться от команды python3.8, чтобы python3 схватывал именно нужный python.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `python3 -V` какую версию питона пишет? `which python3` в какой путь указывает?

Comment: @andreymal python3 -V = Python 3.8.5
which python3 = /home/andrew/bin/python3
which python3.8 = /usr/bin/python3.8